# Pass a value from service to component or service to template

Tags: angular

I have a switch case statement in my Service method

myservice.ts

```
mapGridData(data) {
let colDefObj: GridColumnDef;
const colDefArray = [];
const idToNameMap = {};
let gridDataArray = [];
let aDT: any;
data.attributeMetaData.forEach(subItem => {
  if (subItem.isHidden !== 'true') {
    switch (subItem.attributeDataType) {
      case 'INTEGER':
        aDT = 'numeric';
        break;
      case 'STRING':
        aDT = 'text';
        break;
      case 'DATE':
        aDT = 'date';
        break;
    }
    idToNameMap[subItem.attributeId] = subItem.attributeName;
    colDefObj = new GridColumnDef(subItem);
    colDefArray.push(colDefObj);
  }
});
if (data.attributeValues === null) { data.attributeValues = []; }
gridDataArray = data.attributeValues.map(attributeObj => {
  const row = { objectId: attributeObj.objectId };
  attributeObj.attributeList.forEach(attr => {
    row[idToNameMap[attr.attributeId]] = attr.attributeValue;
  });
  return row;
});
return { gridDataArr: gridDataArray, colDefArr: colDefArray };
}
```

I am using this service in multiple components like below

mycomponent.ts

```
const gridDataObj = this.gridService.mapGridData(data);
```

And in my component html file I need to bind the aDT value like below

```
<kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let column of gridColDef" [filterable]="column.isFilterable === 'true' ? true : false" [sortable]="column.isSortable === 'true' ? true : false" [locked]="false" filter="{{aDT}}">
```

So, how can I bind a service value in my component's template? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: what is aDT ? you assing service data to gridDataObj  but you wrote in filter aDT

Comment: The `aDT` variable is scoped to the `mapGridData()` function and assigned a new value in each iteration of `data.attributeMetaData.forEach`. It isn't assigned to any property of the object returned from the function. How do you wish use it in the component?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I bind a service value in my component's template? Please suggest.

To bind something with `template`, you need a variable at component level (not a variable inside component's function like `let`, `const`, `var`)

In template you are using `{{aDT}}` i.e. not part of any object just plain variable than you should declare it in your component i.e. `public aDT` and assign a value when you receive data from service.

Points to consider:

1. You are not assigning any `aDT` value to any object in your service as pointed out by @Michael D in comments, you just declared a variable, and each iteration you just assigned it a new value.
2. You are returning an object through service i.e. `gridDataArray` or `colDefArray`. On your requirements, if you want to render something like :

```
<kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let column of gridColDef" [filterable]="column.isFilterable === 'true' ? true : false" [sortable]="column.isSortable === 'true' ? true : false" [locked]="false" [filter]="column.aDT">
```

then it should be part of `colDefObj` object.

3. Not preferable way. In your `service`

```
.
.
 let gridDataArray = [];
 let aDT: any;
 let aDTArray = []; // declare a variable that holds all the values 
.
.
.
colDefObj = new GridColumnDef(subItem);
colDefArray.push(colDefObj);
aDTArray.push(aDT); // push your values here 
.
.
.
.

return { gridDataArr: gridDataArray, colDefArr: colDefArray, aDT: aDTArray }; // return it here
```

and in `component.ts`

```
public aDT: any[];
public gridDataObj: any ;


const gridDataObj = this.gridService.mapGridData(data);
this.adT = gridDataObj.adtArray ;
this.gridColDef = gridDataObj.colDefArr ;
```

and in `template`

```
<kendo-grid-column 
*ngFor="let column of gridColDef; let i = index" 
[filterable]="column.isFilterable === 'true' ? true : false" 
[sortable]="column.isSortable === 'true' ? true : false" 
[locked]="false" 
[filter]="aDT[i]">
<!-- use on basis of index -->
```

If it helps you somewhere, you should revisit and check your service on how to return `aDT`on your needs.

P.S.

in `template` for `filter` instead of doing `filter={{aDT}}` you should go for `[filter]="aDT"`